# Overloading method with inheret types

Tags: java, polymorphism

```
public class MySmokeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number x = Integer.valueOf(2);
        new MySmokeTest().met(x);
    }

    private void met(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    private void met(Number i) {
        System.out.println("Number");
    }
}
```

I was expecting to get "Integer", but I got "Number".
Why is that happens?
Isn't Polymorphism applied here?

Comment: The method overload is resolved at compile-time. All the compiler knows is that `x` is a `Number`.

Comment: there is not a better workaround than an if/else instanceof structure, right?

Comment: x is a of Type Number, so the called method is met(Number i).  if you call new MySmokeTest().met(2);  or new MySmokeTest().met(Integer.valueOf(2));  the called method will be with Integer met(Integer i) because 2 or Integer.valueOf(2) are integers.